# How to remove duplicate values from an array

Tags: php

The array in question is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 33103
            [offer_id] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 33103
            [offer_id] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: `array_unique()` i think??

Comment: This is the array list
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 33103
            [offer_id] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 33103
            [offer_id] => 4
        )

)

Comment: check duplicate question, u will get the answer.

Comment: array_unique will provide a unique value from it, but I need to remove those value from it

Comment: Array 
 ( 
  [0] => Array 
  ( 
   [product_id] => 33103
   [offer_id] => 4 
  )
  [1] => Array 
  ( 
   [product_id] => 33103 
   [offer_id] => 4 
  )
  [2] => Array 
  ( 
   [product_id] => 33104 
   [offer_id] => 4 
  )
 )


 Output I need is

  [2] => Array 
  ( 
   [product_id] => 33104 
   [offer_id] => 4 
  )

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item)
{
    for ($i = $key + 1; $i < count($items); $i++)
    {
        if ($item['product_id'] = $items[$i]['product_id'] && $item['offer_id'] == $items[$i]['offer_id'])
        {
            unset($items[$key], $items[$i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is your working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de245c68d34e8dae1f0e4c94cbd603ad0f572d18).

Comment: I don't want to get that value, but I want to remove it from list.

Comment: Your question is remove duplicate values right..?

Comment: yeah. I need to remove it

Comment: The solution you have gave will give me the unique value from the array. But I don't want that

Comment: Array 
 ( 
  [0] => Array 
  ( 
   [product_id] => 33103
   [offer_id] => 4 
  )
  [1] => Array 
  ( 
   [product_id] => 33103 
   [offer_id] => 4 
  )
  [2] => Array 
  ( 
   [product_id] => 33104 
   [offer_id] => 4 
  )
 )


 Output I need is

  [2] => Array 
  ( 
   [product_id] => 33104 
   [offer_id] => 4 
  )

Comment: @G-SquareOfficial Check my updated answer now. I made changes as per your requirement